# c# program will only work with breakpoint inserted

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, breakpoints

I have the following piece of code that generates random numbers to be plotted on a bar graph.  However, it only works properly when I have a breakpoint set on a specific line, otherwise, all of the 10 new datapoints come out as exactly the same number.

```
case 3:
                //Add ten data sets to go through all default colors
                DatasetPairing<BarPresentation, BarGraphDataset<GraphableDouble>> datasetPairing;

                foreach (HorizontalBarPlotter<GraphableDouble, GraphableDouble> graphPlotter in this.Data.GraphPlots)
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 11; i++)
                    {
                        datasetPairing = new DatasetPairing<BarPresentation, BarGraphDataset<GraphableDouble>>();
                        datasetPairing.DatasetPresentation = new BarPresentation();
                        datasetPairing.GraphableDataset = GetOneDataset(0, false);
                        graphPlotter.DatasetMap.Add(datasetPairing); //breakpoint set here
                    }
                    List<IAxis> xAxes;
                    xAxes = new List<IAxis>();
                    xAxes.Add(graphPlotter.DetermineXAxis());
                    this.Data.BottomAxes = xAxes;
                    this.Data.TopAxes = xAxes;
                }
                NextStep = "Return to a single dataset and add comment to values for tooltips";
                break;
```

I have no idea why this is happening, and I have never heard of any problem like this before... perhaps it is a bug in visual studio? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Where do you generate the random number?  Maybe you're using a seed value that only changes every second or so?

Comment: What is 'GetOneDataset(0, false);'?

Comment: It doesn't look like you're using the 'i' variable in your for loop. What does your GetOneDataset method do? Does it need 'i' as a seed, or was '0' intended for all 10 iterations?

Comment: Are you using the Random class to generate random number? Are you creating a new Random object every time you need a random number? if yes make the Random object static(or a class variable) and initialize it once

Comment: I've not seen this in .net but in a different language I use often this can happen has the breakpoint causes all threads to get to a safe place to pause execution(normally at the point where they have completed)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no real random numbers, you have only pseudorandom numbers. Creation of random numbers are based on a seed which is usually the current time.

If you create a new object every time you want a new random number it will be the same number because the time didn't change. (Remeber that when you run the application everything is happening in less than a milisecond - when you debug the application, there is a little while between the creation of 2 new Random variables, and hence the random number is different)

You should use one object to create all the random numbers, and use Random.Next() to get new random value.

if you look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9.aspx) of the class Random you will see the following line:

> different Random objects that are created in close succession by a
>   call to the default constructor will have identical default seed
>   values

And the solution is:

> This problem can be avoided by using a single Random object to generate all random numbers. You can also work around it by modifying the seed value returned by the system clock and then explicitly providing this new seed value to the Random(Int32) constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the method you are using to create the random points uses `Random.Next()`. If this is called in quick succession it can return the same values. It may be worth adding a delay with `Thread.Sleep()`.

Comment: There are barely any reasons whatsoever to use Thread.Sleep, and this is not one of them

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Random class make sure you're not creating a new object every time.

from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx):
`using the parameterless constructor to create different Random objects in close succession creates random number generators that produce identical sequences of random numbers. This problem can be avoided by creating a single Random object rather than multiple ones.`

I generally create a single static Random object and always use that for random numbers this way you will not have duplicates